# get net::ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED when working with docker host

Tags: docker, symfony, webpack

I use Docker for my dev local stack .

I configured a host name for my symfony project : 
  the url is : `http://dev.test.proprietes-privees.com/`

In my symfony i tried to config webpack to use my js files inside a twig :

```
{% extends 'base.html.twig' %}

{% block title %} Mon application React{% endblock %}

{% block stylesheets %}
    <link href="/build/app.css" rel="stylesheet">
{% endblock %}

{% block body %}
    <h1> Page d'accueil </h1>
{% endblock %}


{% block javascripts %}
    <script src="/{{ asset('/build/runtime.js') }}"></script>
    <script src="/{{ asset('/build/app.js') }}"></script>
{% endblock %}
```

I got errors :

```
GET http://build/runtime.js net::ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED
GET http://build/app.js net::ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED
```

How can i fixe my docker config to remove this errors ?

Answer (score 0):

problem fixed in dev mode .

i run : `yarn run dev-server`  to launch encore server .
and in my entrypoints.json i edited http://localhost:8080/ with my dev host.

```
{
  "entrypoints": {
    "app": {
      "js": [
        "http://dev.test.proprietes-privees.com/build/runtime.js",
        "http://dev.test.proprietes-privees.com/vendors~app.js",
        "http://dev.test.proprietes-privees.com/build/app.js"
      ],
      "css": [
        "http://dev.test.proprietes-privees.com/build/app.css"
      ]
    }
  }
}
```